# Зачем нужны микроконтроллеры?

Tags: микроконтроллеры

Как я понял, микроконтроллер это вроде запрограммированого мини-компьютера который управляет разными модулями, датчиками и т.п.?

Comment: @Adaus, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 10):

Микроконтроллер - это однокристальный миникомпьютер. То есть в одной микросхеме собран процессор, память, всякие порты ввода-вывода (в обычном компе эти части обычно разнесены). Также микроконтроллеры обычно специализированы для какой-то задачи. Но зато они потребляют мало памяти и места. А также сильно дешевле полноценного компа.